# Collect metrics from a cluster with Prometheus

Tags: c#, prometheus, metrics, prometheus-node-exporter

I have two windows servers running an apllication in C# and a Prometheus server running in a third node, I want to collect metrics from these two but I'm not able to expose the metrics.

my prometheus .yml is the next one

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s 

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
       - alertmanager:9093

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'SERVER-1'

    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['server3:3242']


  - job_name: 'SERVER-2'

    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['server3:3243']
```

and the code in the application is

```
public static readonly Counter metric1= Metrics.CreateCounter("metric_1", "metrica 1");

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var metricServer = new MetricServer(hostname: "server3", port: 3242);
    metricServer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        metric1.Inc();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Everithing looks running fine, but never up the endpoint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md7UC.png)

Comment: Can you open the metric endpoint in browser? Can you see anything at `server_ip:port/metrics`?

Comment: I can open the endponit server3:9090 to see the web interface of prometheus, but not the endpoint server3:3242/metrics

Comment: I understand that you can open Prometheus (you showed a screenshot from it, after all), the question is whether you can open your application that exposes metrics _for_ Prometheus. Unless explicitly configured otherwise, the application must expose metrics via HTTP in plain text under `/metrics` path. In other words, your first step is to see your application metrics in browser by opening `server_ip:port/metrics`, then you can work with Prometheus. Also, if you use a firewall, don't forget to make a rule for the metric endpoint port.